# Cant Figure out how to copy an existing file name into text in another workbook in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am able to run my macro to select an existing File from any directory and copy a specific data range from that file into my new excel sheet.  I want to copy the name of that file name into the new excel sheet as well but I am falling short on what I need to do.

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()

Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim FileName As Variant


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file 
& Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx*),*xlsx*")

If FileToOpen <> False Then

    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    Set FileName = 'I Don't know what to put here
    OpenBook.Sheets(3).Range("A1:F27").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Imported Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial 
    xlPasteValues
    FileName.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Imported Data").Range("A28").Paste
   OpenBook.Close False


End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import Data").Range("A28").Value = FileToOpen`. A filename is not an object, so get rid of the `Set FileName = ` and `FileName.Copy`.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Thank you.  I may eventually get VBA down.